# gitlab-plugin : openConnection between Jenkins Pipeline and Gitlab

Tags: jenkins, groovy, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I want to develop a Jenkins Pipeline in groovy, i have a Stage has role to update commit staus in Gitlab : `.updateGitlabCommitStatus(name: 'someName', state: 'someState')`. My code is outsourced in a Groovy Class:

```
package ...

import com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.*

class GitlabSender {
    def steps
    openConnection() {

        steps.properties([steps.gitLabConnection("application_name"])

    }
    updateGitlabCommitStatus(String name, String state) {

        steps.updateGitlabCommitStatus(name: name, state: state)

    }
}
```

I want to check if my connection is openned  by adding if-else condition or a a bloc try catch before calling `updateGitlabCommitStatus` as

```
if (gitLabConnection(" ") {
   steps.properties([connectionObject])
   call updateGitlabCommitStatus
} else {
   do nothin
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This commit status is most likely a commit build status.

This should be done by Gitlab API function [Post the build status to a commit](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#post-the-build-status-to-a-commit).

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/17/statuses/18f3e63d05582537db6d183d9d557be09e1f90c8?state=success"
```

Example response:

```
{
   "author" : {
      "web_url" : "https://gitlab.example.com/thedude",
      "name" : "Jeff Lebowski",
      "avatar_url" : "https://gitlab.example.com/uploads/user/avatar/28/The-Big-Lebowski-400-400.png",
      "username" : "thedude",
      "state" : "active",
      "id" : 28
   },
   "name" : "default",
   "sha" : "18f3e63d05582537db6d183d9d557be09e1f90c8",
   "status" : "success",
   "coverage": 100.0,
   "description" : null,
   "id" : 93,
   "target_url" : null,
   "ref" : null,
   "started_at" : null,
   "created_at" : "2016-01-19T09:05:50.355Z",
   "allow_failure" : false,
   "finished_at" : "2016-01-19T09:05:50.365Z"
}
```

This solution requires you to get the gitlab api key and then use it.